# Reset Controls Within a Panel to their Starting States

Tags: c#, forms

I suspect that there is a simple answer to this, but finding a straight answer is providing tricky.

I have a set of textboxes/DateTime pickers/RadioButtons, ect within a panel within a form. I want make a button to clear these fields to their initial state, but having to go in and individually code commands to reset/clear these fields seems excessive. Is there a way to collectively fields within a form/panel?

If there is a way to reset em masse, how could one direct it to be localized to a single tab or panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use FOREACH for it.....

like

```
foreach (Control item in panel1.Controls)
{
  if (item is TextBox || item is RadioButton || item is DateTimePicker)
  {
    item.Text = "Initial Value";
   }
}
```

OR

```
if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) || item.GetType() == typeof(RadioButton)   
|| item.GetType() == typeof(DateTimePicker))
{
  item.Text = "Initial Value";
}
```

Comment: Using a ForEach makes a good deal of sense, but the program is presenting an error for the "TextBox" part of the given code: Is a type but is used as a variable. Why is this?

Edit - Given code was changed while submitting this. Now Moot.

Comment: You da man! That's exactly what I needed. While I'm here, is there something similar to .Clear for DateTimePickers and ListBoxes?

Comment: for listbox u need to set empty datasource or you can use lst.Items.Clear();